# IOS Photo Library fetch album name for a given photo

Tags: objective-c, photosframework

I've been looking everywhere but have not been able to find an answer to this.

In IOS PhotosFramework how I take an image/PHAsset and find out what all collections/albums it is assigned to ?

I already know how to get a list of all the albums from there I can also get all images inside each album. But how do I do it the other way around - i.e. for a given PHAsset how to get the name of Album/Collections that are assigned to it.

Here is the code I have to get a list of all albums in Camera Roll:

```
-(void) listAllAlbums{

    PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
    userAlbumsOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedAssetCount > 0"];

    PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:userAlbumsOptions];

    NSLog(@"---------  entered %s  ------------- ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [userAlbums enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"album title %@", collection.localizedTitle);
    }];

    NSLog(@"---------  end of %s  ------------- ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase old Apple commercials... there's an API for that.

If you have a `PHAsset`, you can get the set of albums containing it with [`fetchAssetCollectionsContainingAsset:withType:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetcollection/1618530-fetchassetcollectionscontaininga?language=objc). If you want just user-created albums, pass `PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum` for the *`type`* parameter; if you also want smart albums (like the Camera Roll, or the other automatically collected albums such as Panoramas or Screenshots), call it again and pass `PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum`.

After calling that, you can enumerate through the results and read the `localizedTitle` of each. (By the way, `PHFetchResult` supports `NSFastEnumeration`, so you don't have to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` unless you want to for some reason... you can just use a `for`-`in` loop.)

Comment: Thanks Rickster! This is exactly what I needed. appreciate your help.